# What is the best way to store a chosen language in a bilingual web application?

Tags: php, zend-framework

There are a couple of approaches that come to mind:

1. GET. I.e. something like www.domain.com, www.domain.com/lang/de
2. Session.
3. Database.

I am curious what is an industry standard in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change de default application locale in the bootstrap based on the value stored in a session. This way you get more flexibility if you want to add a new language, you just have to create a new translation file if all of you code is built based on the user local. This will also ease the date/time and money display process since those are also based on the locale.

french locale ie : fr_FR or fr_CA (for french France of french Canada)
english locale id : en_US or en_UK (for english United States or english United Kindom)

and then if you have to display money, the local will set the good money symbol (but won't do the price conversion) (ie fr_FR -> € and fr_CA -> $)

You could base the default language selection based on the geolocation of the user based on his IP address

Comment: Language selection based on geo-locating is _bad_.  There are many countries with multiple official languages, how do you choose which one is correct to the user?

Comment: if you can identify it by region (like Quebec in canada) you can set it easily otherwise you might have to rely on the default language of your application (usually english) or you can simply rely on the web browser language (which i hate by the way, but its an option)

Comment: Technology is not about loving or hating (well, it should not be). Web browser language is there for a reason, and it is actually quite useful.

Comment: @bazmegakapa (and thanks by the way to pointing this out) The technology in itself isn't that bad, its how people implements it that kills me. They rely on that "automated" system to set the language of the website and put the list of alternative languages far away (ie: in the footer). So you have to scroll all the way down to change the language and over that, you have to repeat the process if you ever leave the browser since it's not saved through a cookie.

Answer (score 3):

The Cookie method can become really annoying on a public machine (Internet cafe, etc).

For the best SEO results you should set up your URLs for different languages anyways, but I normally also store the selected language in session. Of course that expires on browser close, but when a user comes to the site, I always check the Accept-Language header, and decide the starting language based on that.

If you have something like an auto-login feature, you can save the selected language in the database too.

Answer (score 2):

You can't store information on GET and plus you need to rewrite the URLS to look like this www.domain.com/lang/de But its really good for make your application search engine friendly.

And for your answer, I will use what you call it GET + Cookies.

Database - you will need a table for that or if you have already a table for your user you will need at least one more field.

Session the users should set they are Language every-time its a bit boring!

Answer (score 2):

The GET method would require the user to go to the start page every single time, even if he has a direct link to something inside. Otherwise you cant use get, or you'll have to include it in every single link. The session method will expire and forget about the user. The database is nice, but the user will have to login AND THEN see the website in his own language. I think the best thing to do is use a cookie.

Comment: Well, it's not really hard to use GET in Zend Framework as it includes a router class which can be configured easily.

Comment: Yes, but still. I guess you'd like the web app to remember the user's choice for the next time he visits. GET on its own will force the user to choose a language every time. You need to store the language code (i.e. "en") somewhere. And the best place to do that is a cookie - it stays on the users computer even when he leaves the website.

Answer (score 1):

Well...

1. with a custom route setup in ZF - and you can probably omit the 'lang' portion.
   it's also really easy to configure and good for SEO.
2. sessions are good way to setup #1 when a user returns to your site
3. database storage is a good way to setup #2 and #1 when a user logs in with their own
   preferences set.

What is also a good way to attempt to do the initial setup is use Zend_Locale to detect the users language via their OS/browser settings.  But, if you do this you should always let users override your detected value (and save it in a session or db setting)

This is something that is entirely up to you.  You'll be hard pressed to find a "standard."